Expectation value in Markov process using backward generator and semigroup
For the past few days, I've been studying continuous time Markov processes. I was making some exercises and ran into trouble with the following: Consider a continuous Markov process. The state space is $K = \{-1, +1\}$ with transition rates specified as by the parameters $v, H > 0$ in the following manner
$$k(-1,+1) = v \quad \text{and} \quad k(+1,-1) = H/v.$$
We are then aksed to compute the following expectation value
$$<e^{x_t}|x_0 = 1>,$$
for some time $t$. Now I found that
$$<e^{x_t}|x_0 = 1> = e \cdot S(t) = e \cdot e^{tL}$$
where S(t) is the semigroup (equivalent of transition matrix) and $L$ is the backward generator. I also found that $L$ is given by
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-v & v\\
H/v & -H/v
\end{pmatrix}$$
However I do not see how I should now interpret $S(t)$, since the question asks me to derive an expression for this expectation value in function of the parameters $v$ and $H$.
Ok, so I found out the expression i already have for the expression value is wrong and I could solve the exercise with the use of the Master equation, however I would like to know how i could sove it using the semigroup and generator formalism. I need to determine the probability at time $t$ to find the state in +1 or -1. I know that
$$\mu_t = \mu_0S(t)$$
where mu_t is the probability row matrix at time $t$ and $\mu_0$ the same at time $0$. So I actually just need to know how i can represent the matrix $S(t) = e^{tL}$.
